# The contract code couldn't be stored when deploying to rinkeby

Tags: gas, gas-limit, out-of-gas, rinkeby, truffle-migration

I was finally able to get some ether funded and geth/mist working and now i am getting the following error when attempting to deploy my contracts to the rinkeby test network. My project is based on the dotta-license project https://github.com/cryppadotta/dotta-license but i am using the standard migrate and deploy scripts instead of the typescript ones in the project

The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.

Ive been googling and it seems that the problem could be literally anything. Can anyone give me some help tracking down the issue?

Truffle.js

```
 module.exports = {
      networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 9545,
      network_id: '*' // Match any network id
    },
    rinkeby: {
      host: 'localhost', // Connect to geth on the specified
      port: 8545,
      from: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // default address to use for any transaction Truffle makes during migrations
      network_id: 4,
      gas: 4700000, // Gas limit used for deploys
      gasPrice: 30000000000 // 30 gwei
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Do you have a transaction ID?

Comment: txhash: 0x5bf94a7c2b3d0a951aeb2db3335c5dc6840e03f09981a7339022bb2aa64cba34

Comment: Looks like you might be running out of gas, try raising your gas limit.

Comment: should that be set in the truffle.js file?

Comment: Change `gas: 4700000` to something larger

Comment: changed to gas: 7500000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81117/discussion-between-rick-james-and-raghav-sood).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your failing transaction is using 4700000/4700000 gas, which likely points to an out of gas situation, which is supported by :

1. having a contract deployment take such a perfectly round amount of gas is unlikely
2. the geth trace does not contain any op codes that would indicate a failure in the constructor computation
3. The code at the [contract address](http://deployed%20but%20failed%20contract%20addresses) is empty (`0x`)

Try increasing your gas limit for the rinkeby network (but keep it <=7400000, or you will exceed the network block gas limit).